# From two Tensors (labels, inputs) to DataLoader

Tags: pytorch

I'm working with two tensors, inputs and labels, and I want to have them together to train a model. I'm using torch 1.7, but I can't use the function `TensorDataset()` and then apply `DataLoader()`, due to some incompatibilities with other packages when I use `TensorDataset()`. There is another solution to my problem?

**Summary:**
2 Tensors --> DataLoader without using `TensorDataset()`

Comment: I actually use TensorDataset together with DataLoader and it works for me. What is the problem you are running into, can you share a code example?

Comment: Is a problem with the lib that i'm using, syft. I use it to implement Federated Learning techniques, and it implements a partial copy of pytorch lib, that's why i can't use TensorDataset() :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct your own custom [`DataSet`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57648945/1714410):

```py
class MyDataSet(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    super(MyDataSet, self).__init__()
    # store the raw tensors
    self._x = x
    self._y = y

  def __len__(self):
    # a DataSet must know it size
    return self._x.shape[0]

  def __getitem__(self, index):
    x = self._x[index, :]
    y = self._y[index, :]
    return x, y
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Shai !

Comment: one more question, can I train a nn.module (using MNIST, for example data tensors and labels) using tersors instead of Dataloader?